# Usage of Status Quo

Tags: word-usage

My friend want to know the current state of her hotel reservation. She wrote

> Can I know the status quo

Is it a correct usage ?

Comment: Correct in the sense that some ageing professor of linguistics wouldn't query it or correct in the sense that she wouldn't be regarded as highly eccentric?

Answer (score 4):

A clearer way to communicate your friend's request would have been to ask after the *status* of her reservation.

*Status quo* is a term that applies to a broader context than her actual question, and it is more typically used when comparing current processes to hypothetical changes, particularly at a political, organizational, or societal level.

Answer (score 2):

It means ‘the existing state of affairs’, and is a post-classical Latin term, probably derived from ‘in statu quo’ (in the state in which . . .).

It is seldom necessary to use it, and neither necessary nor appropriate when inquiring about something as mundane as a hotel reservation, where it sounds pretentious.

Comment: It sounds completely wrong to me, not just pretentious. If you intend to make sure nothing has changed, it would work to inquire on status quo... At least that is the meaning it has taken on.

Answer (score 0):

Per Merriam-Webster:

> Status quo: the current situation : the way things are now
>
> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/status%20quo

Seems like a safe usage, if she is inquiring about the "current state" of her hotel reservation.

Comment: It may fit grammatically and according to the dictionary, but it's certainly not idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 0):

To fully understand the expression, you have to realize that it is short for "**status quo ante**", meaning, word by word, "the state that was before" ; ("was" is not explicitly written in Latin, when the meaning is obvious).